# Performing a sort using k1,1 only

Tags: linux, sorting, text, ascii

Assume you have an unsorted file with the following content:

```
identifier,count=Number
identifier, extra information
identifier, extra information
...
```

I want to sort this file so that for each id, write the line with the count first and then the lines with extra info. I can only use the sort unix command with option -k1,1 but am allowed to slightly change the lines to get this sort.

As an example, take

```
a,Count=1
a,giulio
aa,Count=44
aa,tango
aa,information
ee,Count=2
bb,que
f,Count=3
b,Count=23
bax,game
f,ee
c,Count=3
c,roma
b,italy
bax,Count=332
a,atlanta
bb,Count=78
c,Count=3
```

The output should be

```
a,Count=1
a,atlanta
a,giulio
aa,Count=44
aa,information
aa,tango
b,Count=23
b,italy
bax,Count=332
bax,game
bb,Count=78
bb,que
c,Count=3
c,roma
ee,Count=2
f,Count=3
f,ee
```

but I get:

```
aa,Count=44
aa,information
aa,tango
a,atlanta
a,Count=1
a,giulio
bax,Count=332
bax,game
bb,Count=78
bb,que
b,Count=23
b,italy
c,Count=3
c,Count=3
c,roma
ee,Count=2
f,Count=3
f,ee
```

I tried adding spaces at the end of the identifier and/or at the beginning of the count field and other characters, but none of these approaches work.

Any pointer on how to perform this sorting?

EDIT: 
 if you consider for example the products with id starting with a, one of them has info 'atlanta' and appears before Count (but I wand Count to appear before any information). In addition, bb should be after b in alphabetical order for the ids. To make my question clearer: How can I get the IDs sorted by alphabetical order and such that for a given ID, the line with Count appears before the others. And how to do this using sort -k1,1 (This is a group project I am working on and I am not free to change the sorting command) and maybe changing the content (I tried for example adding a '~' to all the infos so that Count is before)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to tell sort, that comma is used as field separator

```
sort -t, -k1,1
```

For ASCII sorting make sure LC_ALL=C and LANG and LANGUAGE are unset

Comment: This is probably the simplest thing to do thx, however, I can't change the options of sort (just sort -k1,1) as this is part of a larger program and other people from my group already adapted their code to this constraint. Is there a solution where I just edit the characters in my file?

Comment: @giulio you could replace the commas with whitespace (space or tab), then the -k1,1 should work as desired

Comment: actually no. When I replace the comma by a space for example, consider the id 'a', then its Count will show up after 'atlanta'. That's why I tried adding a special character before every 'info' like ~ so that the rows corresponding to 'info' would be placed after the rows with Count (since ~ appears after C in the ascii table). However, it didn't work as expected

Comment: @giulio: Assuming Count is always uppercase, and infos are always lowercase as they are in your examples Count will be the first for every key.

Comment: I just tried with the input I gave as example (where I replaced the comma by a white space) and got atlanta before Count (please note that I set LC_ALL='C')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70493/discussion-between-rbtux-and-giulio).